# Spatial plot of the breakpoints in the bfast lite

Tags: r, plot, time-series, raster

In `R`, I am using the `bfastlite` function from the `bfast` package to identify breaks in my time-series (TS). The model found 2 breakpoints which I can plot in a line graph using the plot function.

My goal is to plot spatially the breaks, that is, to link the breaks with the pixels in my study site. Is there a way to do this? From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bfast/bfast.pdf) I couldn't find a solution nor in the internet. An example of what I want to achive is:

[image: bfast spatial plot example]
In the above image the cross sign indicates the pixel with break (either in the trend or seasonal component).

Below is an example using the data from the package:

```
library(bfast)

plot(simts) # stl object containing simulated NDVI time series
datats <- ts(rowSums(simts$time.series))
# sum of all the components (season,abrupt,remainder)
tsp(datats) <- tsp(simts$time.series) # assign correct time series attributes
plot(datats)
# Detect breaks
bp = bfastlite(datats)

plot(bp)
```

If needed I can share my dataset and my actualy code.

`RStudio` 2023.12.0+369, `R` 4.3.2, Windows 11.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not clear what you want the final image to look like.

Comment: You might want to take a look to the `bfastSpatial` package

Comment: When installing the `bfastSpatial` following this example (https://github.com/loicdtx/bfastSpatial) I am getting the following error: ERROR: dependency 'gdalUtils' is not available for package 'bfastSpatial'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.2/library/bfastSpatial'

And I can't install the `gdalUtils` package because it says: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gdalUtils’ is not available for this version of R.

Comment: Just managed to install the bfastSpatial package. The order for the installation of the packages should be:

`library(devtools)

devtools:::install_github("gearslaboratory/gdalUtils")

install_github('loicdtx/bfastSpatial')`

But I don't want to use the bfast monitor as my main time-series analysis tool because I am interested in all the available breaks.